# Creating thumbnails using NSImageView and a custom NSView

Tags: cocoa, calayer, nsview, nsimageview

I need to do the following in my cocoa app (OS X):

- Allow the user to drop an image on an `NSImageView`.
- Once the image is dropped project a fixed size rectangle over the image, indicating the area of the image that will be used as a thumbnail.
- Allow the user to drag the rectangle around to pinpoint the required thumbnail.
- Once positioned, the user clicks a button which saves images and thumbnail to files.

It is the second bullet that I would like some feedback on. My idea is to do the following:

- In IB drop an `NSImageView` on my view which will accept the image.
- Once the drop is done, create another `NSView` (exact same size as the `NSImageView`) and project it over the `NSImageView` and display the rectangle  for the thumbnail. I will probably have to subclass `NSView` so it is transparent and supports drawing and repositioning of the rectangle.
- Allow the user to drag the rectangle around. Once the user accepts the thumbnail position, create the thumbnail from the image by projecting the rectangle on the image in `NSImageView`.

I understand that to work with overlapping views I need to turn on layers (`setWantsLayer: YES`) for the parent view. However, I found some mixed reports on this, stating that overlapping instances of `NSView` can't be done and this can only be done using `CALayer`. Also if there are easier ways to capture a thumbnail off an `NSImageView`, input is much appreciated.